# reading PHP session data from asynchronous request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

When making an asynchronous call from javascript to a php file, how do you ensure that php $_session information (which is cookie based i believe) is sent along with the asynchronous request?

I've heard that cookie information is sent with all HTTP requests, but I've found that jquery's $.get() and $.post() requests fail to allow the receiving PHP file to read $_session information.

The receiving php file trying to read $_session information in the normal way:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
.....
```

if the receiving php file is accessed directly via in a web browser, the session information is accessible.

Thanks!

* update ***

I've found that it's the session_start() command that fails.  That command causes the following file to return '0' instead of the expected 'no session available' response.

whois.php:

```
 $s = session_start();
 if($s){
    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
        if(isset($_POST['name'])){
            echo $_SESSION['user']." ".$_POST['name'];
        }elseif(isset($_GET['name'])){
            echo $_SESSION['user']." ".$_GET['name'];
        }
    }else{
        echo 'no user specified';
    }
 }else{
    echo 'no session available';
 }
```

Just to be thorough, I tested the above php file by navigating to in a web browser via its direct URL, and accessed the php session and outputed the correct response. I wonder why it doesn't work asynchronously...

At Pekka's request, here is the php file that makes the asynchronous request:

```
 <?PHP
 session_start();
 if(isset($_GET['user'])){
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_GET['user'];
 }

 ?>

 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#response").html('---');

        $("#form").submit(function(){
            var formData = $(this).serialize();

            $.post("whois.php",formData,function(data){
                $("#response").html(data);
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <form id="form">
        <input name="name" type="text"/>
        <input name="submit" type="submit"/>
    </form>
    <div id="response">
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: This is not correct. When you make an ajax call, the session id is sent in a cookie along with the request and your php file that receive the request is able to read the session data. If it doesn't, then you are doing something wrong, like making your cookies http only(i think).

Comment: Yeah, this should work. The session cookie should be carried in every Ajax request.

Comment: That's what I've been reading, that it should work... but it doesn't.  Are there any default server settings or default PHP settings that could throw things off? I've tried it on both Apache and IIS based localhosts without luck.

Comment: Can you show some more code, e.g. how you're making the Ajax request?

Comment: @Twisted1919: httponly cookies are simply not readable from within a JS script. They will STILL be sent in the http headers for all ajax requests. if they weren't, ajax would be pretty useless because you wouldn't be able to maintain logins for MANY sites .

Comment: Well, I honestly don't know what happened, but the code I posted above now works.   I believe all I did was delete some white space before posting it for you to see.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Heh, cool! (It was our magical presence that made it work, of course.)

Comment: @MarcB - Yup, it makes sense, i had a doubt about that, but it's clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

i think that the real problem is in PHP session management. If you do `session_start()` its the same like if you do `fopen(SESSION_FILE, 'rw')` - in other words you are opening session file for writing. This is ok for the first request. But in the same time second request is accepted by server and is trying to do exactly the same : open the session file for writing . This will fail on many systems. But still its strange, i would expect first request to be completed , while second request is waitig for the first one to call `session_destroy()` or `session_write_close()`. Once this is done or timeouted , second request may access the session and continue with the work ... :)